# How to remove specific duration from video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, video, ffmpeg

i've tried many ways to solve the problem, i also tried this code before

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf trim=3:8 cut.mp4
```

but for the result, the audio is still there but the video is gone. all i want is the video and audio both are removed. 
can anyone help me how resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf "select='not(between(t,3,8))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -af aselect='not(between(t,3,8))',asetpts=N/SR/TB cut.mp4
```

Comment: i've tried that, and it says Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'

Comment: Looks like you have to escape the commas inside the select.. 'not(between(t\,3\,8))'